# Python Mechanize HTTP Error 403: request disallowed by robots.txt

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup, mechanize, robots.txt

So, I created a Django website to web-scrape news webpages for articles..
Even though i use mechanize, i they still telling me:

```
HTTP Error 403: request disallowed by robots.txt
```

I tried everything, look at my code(Just the part to scrape):

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
page = br.open(web)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_equiv(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
    #BeautifulSoup 
htmlcontent = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlcontent)
```

I tried too to use de br.open before the set_hande_robots(Flase) ,etc. It didn't work either.

Any way to get trough this sites?

Comment: They are disallowed because those sites don't want any bot to access their resources. There might be legal terms. You should stay away from them.

Answer (score 5):

You're setting `br.set_handle_robots(False)` after `br.open()`

It should be:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_equiv(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
page = br.open(web)
htmlcontent = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlcontent)
```